# Aggregate and group to get last row from the collection in Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

From the below mongo document I want to get the last record within versions.errors.
From the below document I want only the last level, message and timestamp where the message reads "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= AMMO are 0, this value should be equal to 1"

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "objectIdentifier" : {
            "identifier" : {
                "settlementInstanceId" : "3b37de20-e47e-435c-896e-8d9dea0eb63a"
            },
            "objectName" : "SinkPriceZonesWithFercCreditFlag"
        },
        "settlementInstanceId" : "3b37de20-e47e-435c-896e-8d9dea0eb63a",
        "validator" : "SinkPriceZoneFercCreditFlagValidator",
        "@objectName" : "ValidationResult"
    },
    "Versions" : [ 
        {
            "errors" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= ALTE are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= EMTO are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= ENTO are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= IPL are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= ETTO are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= OTP are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "WARN",
                    "message" : "The number of NITS reservations with FERC credit flag associated with priceZone= AMMO are 0, this value should be equal to 1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1531167099204)
                }
],
            "resultSetId" : "56170750-8f1c-4c6a-9ec4-d4fdcfbd8c03",
            "scope" : "COMPLETENESS",
            "validationLevelSeverity" : "WARN",
            "validationResultsIdentifier" : {
                "identifier" : {
                    "objectIdentifier" : {
                        "identifier" : {
                            "settlementInstanceId" : "3b37de20-e47e-435c-896e-8d9dea0eb63a"
                        },
                        "objectName" : "SinkPriceZonesWithFercCreditFlag"
                    },
                    "settlementInstanceId" : "3b37de20-e47e-435c-896e-8d9dea0eb63a",
                    "validator" : "SinkPriceZoneFercCreditFlagValidator"
                },
                "objectName" : "ValidationResult"
            },
            "version" : NumberLong(10014)
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to use aggregate query such as :

```
db.getCollection('ValidationResults').aggregate(
{"$match": { "_id.objectIdentifier.objectName" : "SinkPriceZonesWithFercCreditFlag", "_id.settlementInstanceId": "3b37de20-e47e-435c-896e-8d9dea0eb63a"}},
{ "$unwind": "$Versions" })
```

Not sure how to use $group on the timestamp field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get last element from an array you can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator and pass `-1` as an index. From the docs:

> If negative, $arrayElemAt returns the element at the idx position, counting from the end of the array.

```
db.ValidationResults.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: { 
                "_id.objectIdentifier.objectName" : "SinkPriceZonesWithFercCreditFlag", 
                "_id.settlementInstanceId": "3b37de20-e47e-435c-896e-8d9dea0eb63a"
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$Versions" },
        { 
            $addFields: {
                lastError: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$Versions.errors", -1 ] }
            } 
        }
])
```

Comment: Is there a way to only display this particular row without $addFields, I am just asking. I am trying to write this aggregate function in Java just thought of checking.

Comment: @janopan try project instead of `addFields`. As a result you'll get only last row